# The app configuration in App Studio does not exist for the id 4f2c0a7d-6ab9-4594-b2b6-bec7ccd7d0e6 in the organization you are currently logged into

Tags: microsoft-teams, app-id

This question is regarding the microsoft team app.
When i try to run the app created by other developers using visual studio microsfot team tool kit,
i get following error.
The app configuration in App Studio does not exist for the id 4f2c0a7d-6ab9-4594-b2b6-bec7ccd7d0e6 in the organization you are currently logged into.

I have logged into the teams and also uploaded the app package and allowed it for all teams.

Interestingly the app id in the admins.teams.microsoft.com is always different then the one in the client.

Regards
Ashish

Comment: Did other developers tenant and your tenant is same? could you please check and update?

Comment: are you still facing the issue?

Comment: No i am not facing the issue. By the way microsoft have moved to a new version of tools which is incompatablie to existing version